# Get state from url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

Want to get state matching specific url. For example, if I have:

```
stateProvider.state('a', {
    url: '/a?foo?baz'
});
```

I need something like this:

```
state.resolveFromUrl('/a?foo=bar&baz=qux'); // returns state 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `$state.get()` method which returns list of all states.

So, for example, using loDash, you can

```
$scope.resolveFromUrl = function(url){
    return _.find($state.get(), {url: url});
};
```

For updated question:

```
$scope.resolveFromUrl = function(url){
    return _.find($state.get(), function(state){ 
        return state.url.split('?')[0].indexOf(url.split('?')[0]) === 0;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but that will not work in any case (see updated question)

Comment: Just add some machinations with split and indexOf. :) See updated answer.